# Azure devops Work Item types API returns string instead of JSON

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I try to get work item types via PowerShell, I get a string instead of the expected JSON.
This is my PowerShell code:

```
$Token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
$JsonContentType = 'application/json-patch+json'
$Header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + $Token;accept=$JsonContentType}
$BaseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organisation)/"
$Uri = $BaseUri + "$Project/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=5.1"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $Header
$Result
```

I also tried with the newer version 6.0, but it also returns a string instead of JSON.
Other responses are fine, for example:

```
$Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organisation)/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1"
$Projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method get -Headers $Header
```

This correctly returns JSON, or if I request a work item, I also get JSON.

I cannot figure out why this is...

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I completely forgot to have a go at this as I was pulled into some other projects that took precedence. I will try this out right now. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Sadly, the proposed answer didn't work (See my comment there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Invoke-Rest-Method tries to return a PSCustomObject, which does not support properties without names and thus the conversion fail and you get the plain string back:

From [Invoke-RestMethod fails to parse JSON response](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7880#issuecomment-425254776)

> The problem is that by default, Invoke-RestMethod tries to convert the
> json to a PSCustomObject. However, PSCustomObject doesn't support a
> property without a name. In your script, add -AsHashTable to get an
> object that supports this.
>
> However, I think that a warning instead of an error may be better here
> and have the resulting object not contain that property by default.

## Solution for Powershell 6 and above

You can convert the string yourself to a data structure that supports empty properties (like a hashtable). This can be done using the [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--convert-a-json-string-to-a-hash-table) method as shown below

```
$Token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
$Header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + $Token}
$BaseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/"
$Project = "test"
$Uri = $BaseUri + "$Project/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=5.1"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $Header

# Check if type is string, then convert to a hashtable
if ($Result.GetType().Name -eq "String") {
    $jsonRes = ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable -InputObject $Result
} else {
    $jsonRes = $Result
}

$jsonRes
```

## Solution for Powershell 5 and below

If you are using an older verison of powershell you will need to parse the string into a hashmap yourself or using a thrid party tool. (I am not aware of any built in cmdlet that does this at least).

One option could be to use the JavaScriptSerializer .NET class, which is done in the [Poshstache module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Poshstache/0.1.9/Content/ConvertFrom-JsonToHashtable.ps1). The code is available on the link so you should be able to review it and possibly customize it to fit your needs

Comment: Sorry for the super late response. I don't have '-ashashtable' as an available parameter, so I'm guessing you're using a newer version of PowerShell than I do (V5.1). And the command doesn't seem to work without it :-/

Comment: Yes you are right, you will need powershell 6 or above to use the `-ashashtable` flag. For powershell 5 I am not aware of any built in way to convert the json string to a hashmap, but should ot be to hard to implement such a method. I updated my answer with some suggestions on how to do that, please have a look

Comment: That's great, thanks, I will give that a try. I kinda wonder why all the other returns from Azure DevOps are fine, but just this one is broken -__-

Comment: And that seems to work perfectly, many thanks, I don't think I would have ever found that without your help.